# How can an XMLHttpRequest be used to send JSON data and which method is better to use from GET or POST?

Tags: javascript, post, get, xmlhttprequest

Which method from `GET` or `Post` is more suitable to use for the code displayed below and what are its advantages from one another? 
The code is supposed to return data based on a user's location.

```
  function findPark (latitude,longitude) {
  var myReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var serviceURL = "https://www.ratemyPlace.prg/getRating?";
  serviceURL += "lat=" + latitude;
  serviceURL += "&lng=" + longitude;
  myReq.addEventListener("load", myListener);
  myReq.open("GET", serviceURL);
  myReq.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use GET.**

- this looks like a read-only operation with no side effects
- it has no message body

see also: [What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)